# Criterion for 3-qubit separability

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

Is there a necessary and sufficient criterion to verify if a 3-qubit density matrix is separable?

I understand that for 2-qubit systems one can use the Peres-Horodecki criterion which is a sufficient condition. For 3-qubits, all I've found so far is this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0308032 which I'm having some difficulties to understand. Is this the only available option?